# I cannot count total files in folder which dose not exist in database and without ignore files by php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to list all my files in a particular folder which files is not entry at mysqli database. After done this well, want make a pagination for 20 files par page.

Here is my problem: I cannot count total files which dose not exist in database and without ignore files also.

Here my pagination not display any output also.

```
<?php
// Query in database
$sqlFind = 'SELECT `link` FROM `movie`';
$result = mysqli_query($dbh, $sqlFind);
$db = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
array_push($db, $row[0]);

// Check files
$ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store');
$limit = 23;
$page = (int)$_GET['page'];
if(!($page>0)) $page = 1;
$offset = ($page-1)*$limit;

$directory = C:/xampp/htdocs/movie/;
$files = scandir($directory,1);

/****** Make a limit display result at par page *****/
$files1 = array_slice($files, $offset, $limit);  

if ( $files1 !== false ) {
       $y = 0;
   foreach ($files1 as $i => $value) {
       if (!in_array($value, $ignore)) { // check ignore type file
       if (!in_array($value, $db)) {     // check with database
        // File not exists in both
            echo $y.': '.$value."<br>";
       ++$y;
       }
       }
   }
################
$total = count($files1); // How to count total without ignore and with database match
################
$totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); //calculate total pages


$pagLink = "<ul class='pagination'> Go to: "; 
for ($z=1; $z<= $total_pages; $z++) {
// Can't see anything at pagination
$pagLink .= "<li class=''><a href='".$thispage."?  url=".$thisurl."&page=".$z."'>".$z."</a></li>";
}
echo $pagLink . "</ul>";

} else {   echo 0;}  //!==false
```

Comment: `$directory = C:/xampp/htdocs/movie/;` That's a syntax error, you need to put the pathname in quotes.

Comment: `array_slice()` never returns `false`. Why do you have `if ($files1 !== false)`. If you want to know if the array contains files, use `if (!empty($files1))`.

Comment: $directory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/movie/"; writing mistake here. if ($files1 !== false) is not important for my. I removed it. problem is in counting total items. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_dff` to remove all the names from the DB and ignored names before you do the pagination.

```
$files = scandir($directory, 1);
$files = array_diff($files, $db, $ignore);
$files1 = array_slice($files, $offset, $limit);
```

Then you don't need all the `in_array()` checks in the loop. It should just be:

```
foreach ($files1 as $i => $value) {
    echo "$i: $value<br>";
}
$total = count($files);
```

Comment: Please a subsidiary question sir: Why pagination not displaying any thing? Have any problem there.

Comment: Done it. A writing mistake also here $totalPages as $total_Pages. Thank you sir.